# Store and process big data in matlab

Tags: matlab, bigdata, montecarlo, markov-chains

I want to do a Markov Chain Monte Carlo simulation. Therefore I need to store the generated states. The problem is that I want to run my program a while and generate a lot of states but MATLAB shows me the 'OUT OF MEMORY' error. Because I don't need to know the full history of my states the whole time (I only need the preceding state to generate the next one) I thought I could store my generated states after each 10000 iteration steps and only keep the last one. Then at the end I want to do some calculations for example like mean, variance and plot a histogram of the generated data and eventually plot the data with the big-data plot: http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/40790-plot-big

I generate a struct, storing the number of dimensions and a vector with coordinates according to this dimension and another vector of the same size. After that initialization I use a for loop to generate my following Markov-Chain

```
state(1) = struct('dim', 3 ,'coords',rand(3,1), 'vals', rand(3,1));
state(10000) = struct('dim', [], 'coords', [], 'vals', []);
for i = 2:10000
state(i) = generateNewState(state(i-1));
end
```

How can I store my generated state-data and proceed with the next 10000 states. Then append them to the existing .mat file and go on until I generated say 1e10 states. And then use the data to do calculations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this was sometime ago, but maybe it will still help some one. I solved my problem by not using .mat files, but instead wrote the structs to an csv-file. I created a formatting string which resulted in an tabular format and wrote the struct elements according to that into my csv file with `fprintf()`. But before that I had to transform my struct array to an cell array to be able to easily access my struct content. For this I used `struct2table()` and then `table2cell()`, so that I obtained some cell array `temp` and then I called `fprintf(fid, FormatString, temp{:})`. Properly performed it would result in a header and in each row one markov state and each dimension of the markov state would have a separate coloumn.

After my simulation I used the MapReduce technique in Matlab to process my csv file. So basically I went through the data with map and reduce algorithms to calculate according mean, variance, count, min and max statistics. After that I used min and max to define bin edges for my histogramm and went through my data a second time to calculate bin counts with an according MapReduce algorithm. Since these algorithms are designed to work in parallel, it was no problem to iterate 2 times through my data which consisted of  about 50 million markov chain states, where each state could have several 100 dimensions. It was more a problem of storage, since this data in the csv file would make up to 10 GB or more. So one should be careful  when using a hard drive which is FAT or FAT32 formatted.... There a certainly more clever ways of storing the data, but I have chosen csv files, because they can be processed within MATLAB with the help of the MapReduce algorithms.

In the end I could not use plot-big from file-exchange, but I is not difficult to extract one coloumn of the data, which would usually still fit in the memory. With this one coloumn, which describes the corresponding dimension of each markov state, one could plot the evolvement of this dimension, by just plotting every 1000th element or so. Saving the figure and closing it to reduce the workload of the PC and then repeat this for every dimension, to get an overview of the simulated data. 
I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The first idea I got:
**1.** Maybe you can calculate all variables you need at every step? 
For example:

```
n = 10000;
for i = 1:n
state = generateNewState(stateOld);
mean = mean + state/n;
stateOld = state;
end;
```

This let you calculate mean without saving all values of states.
Same thing you can do with histogram: if you now values of axis for histogram you can create array and calculate in which interval state get in at this step:

```
if (state < 0.1 )
inter1 = inter1 + 1;
elseif (state < 0.2)
inter2 = inter2 + 1;
...
```

It is a lot of code, but this works.
And so on and so on with others.
2. And the second way: you can calculate it for first 10000 steps, save it in excel (`xlswrite` function) and then use loop to rewrite values of states with increasing `i`. In this case you save all values and will load it back in the same way.
You can see I use state like `double` not like `struct`, but it's easy to implement it to `struct`.

Comment: OK the idea with this moving average also crossed my mind but I have struggle with the idea of my histogram. I don't know the range of my values at start so I can't define my bins a priori. And why do you use xls files instead of mat files? Is there some advantage concerning the read/write performance?

Comment: hm yeah it's important - you try to do universal algorithm for any distribution (then it's really hard to define bins) or just specifically for your own. Because for your own you can go this way - calculate simulation for a 1000 states and can see the limits (it will be not really accurate, but it is make possible to understand the order of magnitude). Then set bins and start calculation for a big values of states.
Ah sry about xls - it is my own habit, because I'm working with people not all of them have Matlab, so sometimes I introduce results to them in xls. By the way I feel .mat is faster